# Restrict user to create directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rhel

I'm creating users called 'vinod', and want to restrict vinod from creating sub-directories in his home directory. However, he should be able to upload files.

Is there a way we can restrict user from creating sub-directories in home directory, but still be able to upload files?

It would be great help if someone can help me.

Comment: How is said using "uploading" files? Would `chroot` work?

Comment: Does "restrict to create subfolders" mean that the user is _not_ allowed to create directories, or that they ore _only_ allowed to create directories?

Comment: You say upload. So maybe a [locked-down SFTP-user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23099945/5114441) would be sufficient?

Comment: The only way to do it would be with some sort of restricted shell (or other program).

Comment: Can you tell us why. It may help with producing a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Both subdirectory creation AND new file creation require the same permission - Write access to the directory.

From the system's viewpoint, there is little difference between the two actions.

Comment: Well, from permissions point of view, yes, but a restricted shell and specifically allowing `mkdir` (and maybe `rmdir`) as command(s) would be a possible hack. See: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/65822 . Alternatively if it is `ssh` you may define whitelisted commands with [`only`](http://at.magma-soft.at/sw/blog/posts/The_Only_Way_For_SSH_Forced_Commands/)